# Which folder a document is in Lotus Domino

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript

Is it possible export (@whichfolders) from Lotus to excel?

I created a view, with column "folder", with function @whichfolders.

On lotus view this configuration returns the correct info but, when i try export this view to excel, excel "print" a strange characters...

Lotus: "Inbox/resolved"

Excel: "c^_"

tks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, @WhichFolders is a very specialized formula intended only to be used in the mail template.  It may not be built to support exporting properly from a view.

I would try, however, wrapping the formula in a call to @Text, just to see if that helps.

```
@Text(@WhichFolders)
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_WHICHFOLDERS_FUNCTION.html

Comment: hi! tks 4 your answer! i tried @text(@whichfolders) but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation of `NotesDocument.FolderReferences` you must provide special views: $FolderInfo and $FolderRefInfo - just by copying from mail template.

If it doesn't help, try to use hat LotusScript method in exporting code.

Comment: You also have to change NotesDatabase.FolderReferencesEnabled to True

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you should be able to test to see if you have any documents in Folder X, then write the name of the Folder X, then write meta data of the message/document into a text file that could be imported to Excel. Then move on to the next Folder. If Folder = "" then end.

I am sure that this is available via LotusScript. You might be able to get what you need using NotesView objects. There is a property for Name. I have written code in the past that would access a View object when it is actually a Folder.